# importxml scrape the value from table

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to parse a part of a website https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-technical `TSTOCHRSI(14) 100.000 Overbought` is the part im looking at and all need the 100 portions of that

I never tried this before so honestly, I don't even know where to start. the code I have is probably terribly wrong

if anyone could help that would be awesome, thx

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.eventbrite.com/d/wa--everett/even ts/","//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/main/section/div/header/main/div[2]/div/div")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEx(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-technical", 
 "table", 2), 4, 2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking to do, if i were to change the tabs from "hourly" to another tab say "1 min." how would it differ? since the website url does not change is it even possible? big time thanks for the above answer!

Comment: if the url does not change you can't get values from those tabs

Comment: got it, thaanks!

Comment: If you have a min could i get the real time price of gold from this site https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold with the same format as the other ones would be a big help thx again!!!

Comment: https://imgur.com/w00jLav whatever you can get from that box would be great. thanks a lot!

Comment: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold", "//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']")`

Comment: Would it be possible to combine the 1.45 and -0.10% in one box? if not this is more than enough! thanks! https://imgur.com/a/R4tDy1v

Comment: try: `={INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold", "//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']"), 1, 1), 
  INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold", "//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']"), 1, 2)&" ("&
  TEXT(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold", "//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']"), 1, 4), "0.00%")&")"}`

Comment: YES!! THANK YOU!!